# Get only specific relationship type in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have a Person node which has PersonId property and a Document Node which has DocumentId property.

Relationship is as we have in emails like,

```
(person)-[:SENT]->(doc)
(doc)-[:TO]->(person)
(doc)-[:CC]->(person)
(doc)-[:BCC]->(person)
```

Now when I fire queries as shown in image attached, In the second query the 4th column with SIZE function gives "1" in 2nd row.

[image]

Can you say why I'm getting count of 1 over there ? even I'm specifying relation type :TO. Let me know if you need anything else.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What version of neo4j are you using (perhaps this is a bug that has been fixed)? I cannot reproduce the issue. Can you show sample data that causes this behavior?

Comment: Never mind, see my answer for 2 scenarios that can explain the behavior you saw.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The relationship type (`:TO`) is not part of the `MATCH`, it's part of the `RETURN`. The rows (paths) returned from the second query are exactly the same as those returned from the first query, but you're simply returning an additional "column", which is the number of paths `(d)-[:TO]->(rc)`, *between the pair of nodes corresponding to that row*. The pair of nodes is the same, so it will give the same result (1).

I imagine the relevant part of your graph looks like this:

[image: graph]

Querying your graph for the pattern `(p:Person { PersonId: 4})-[s:SENT]->(d:Document)-[r]->(rc:Person)` will return two matching paths:

- `(person 4)-[:SENT]->(document 10)-[:BCC]->(person 3)`
- `(person 4)-[:SENT]->(document 10)-[:TO]->(person 3)`

Notice how the nodes involved are the same for both rows.

Now, for each match/row, you're returning *the number of `:TO` relationships between the document and the recipient of that row*, which is 1 because there is obviously a single `:TO` between document 10 and person 3.

The `:TO` in the `RETURN` part of your query is in essence not related to the `r` relationship in your `MATCH`. First, you use a `MATCH` to retrieve the nodes/relationships in your graph that you are interested in, then you act upon those nodes/relationships (the `RETURN`).

Comment: But the puzzle is why there should be a `(d)-[:TO]->(rc)` match at all in the indicated row, since in that row the relationship type is `BCC` -- not `TO`.

Comment: @cybersam: there is no puzzle. `[r]` will match **any** relationship from a :Document  to a :Person; there is a BCC from person 4 to person 3, as well as a TO, so both paths will match. In both cases you are returning the number of TO's between persons 4 and 3, which is exactly 1.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, So does it mean that in RETURN statement, it will not consider the Relationship Type ?

Comment: @Eagle_Eye: it certainly *does* consider the relationship type. It returns you exactly what you asked for: the number of `:TO` relationships between a document and a recipient. I updated my answer with a more thorough explanation.

Comment: @Jan Van den bosch: Thanks for the explanation, After playing a bit with it, I found if I add 'r' in SIZE columns relationship like this `SIZE((d)-[r:TO]->(rc))` then it doesn't give 1 count which is of I assume BCC relationship. Can you explain this behavior ?

Comment: @Eagle_Eye: that's right. The identifier `r` is bound to the relationship between document and recipient: `:BCC` in the first row, `:TO` in the second row. You are requesting the number of `r` relationships between a document and a person, with the additional constraint that the relationship is of type `:TO`, which obviously only holds when `r` is actually of type `:TO`.

Comment: @Jan Van den bosch: So that means, considering our relevant part, When `r` was absent, It iterated through both paths and checked if any `:TO` relation exists between both nodes, which was true for both iteration, So got count 1 in both iteration, But when I specified `r`, it also checked relationship type should be `:TO` between both nodes which was true for only 2nd row, hence I got count 1 in only for 2nd row.

Comment: @Eagle_Eye: when you didn't specify `r`, it checked whether there was *any* `:TO` relationship between the nodes (yes, there is one - I can see it). When you specified `r`, it checked whether there was an `r` relationship (yes, obviously), of type `:TO` (no - only for the second row). Now try specifying only `[r]` and see what happens.

Comment: @Jan Van den bosch: If I specify [r], it gives 1 for all the paths in SIZE column, meaning that all the paths has some relationship, either TO,CC or BCC. Right ?

Comment: @Eagle_Eye: yes, they must have that relationship because otherwise, they wouldn't have matched in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least 2 scenarios for the behavior you saw:

1) There are 2 docs sent from person 4 to person 3. One was sent as a `BCC`, and one was sent as a `TO`.

2) A doc sent from person 4 to person 3 specified person 3 as a `BCC` recipient as well as a `TO` recipient.